# lightbox prev next position change

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, lightbox, scriptaculous

I am using lightbox slideshow and it is working fine, there is Next-Prev button also in that. But I want it to show at the bottom of the image and also currently it will show only when I mouseover the image, is there any way to show it permanently.

I am using Lightbox v2.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nextLink {
    background: url(http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/images/nextlabel.gif) no-repeat 100% 85% !important;
}

#prevLink {
    background: url(http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/images/prevlabel.gif) no-repeat 0% 85% !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi fantactuka,

thanks for your help, using this i am able to change the position of the previous next button from top to bottom of the slideshow. 

but could you help to make it appear all the time, that is now it is showing only when we mouseover

thanks again
deve

Comment: you should remove styles from `#nextLink:hover` and `#prevLink:hover`

Comment: Hey,

Thanks again for your so much help to me.

Cheers
deve

Answer (score -1):

Use this as calling for the lightbox: `.lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true });`

Comment: That is only valid for the [jQuery implementation of Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/). The [official Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) relies on Prototype and works automatically, it does not require a JavaScript call to initiate.